# Refresh Access Token Python-Fitbit (Orcasgit)

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, fitbit

I can't figure out how to refresh my access token using this: https://github.com/orcasgit/python-fitbit

I've been able to get my Access Token, and Refresh Token.  I've also been able to pull data from fitbit. But after my Access Token Expires I'm lost. I think I'm supposed to create a FitbitOauth2Client object, and use the refresh_token function to get a new token.  Below is the closest I've gotten.

```
tokenfresh=fitbit.FitbitOauth2Client(client_id=ci,client_secret=consumer_secret,access_token=at,refresh_token=rt)
```

I've scoured all over for an answer so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not your code, FitBit provides a new refresh token when you use an older refresh token to generate an access token. You should keep track of this refresh token in order make you code work.
eg.

```
def fitbit_data(credentials):
    client_id = os.environ.get("FITBIT_CLIENT_ID")
    client_secret = os.environ.get("FITBIT_CLIENT_SECRET")

    oauth = fitbit.FitbitOauth2Client(client_id=client_id,
                                      client_secret=client_secret,
                                      refresh_token=str(credentials.get('refresh_token')),
                                      access_token=str(credentials.get('access_token')))
    token = oauth.refresh_token()
    update_refresh_token(token)

    app_client = fitbit.Fitbit(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret,
                           access_token=token.access_token, refresh_token=token.refresh_token)
    steps = app_client.time_series(
        resource='activities/steps',
        period='1d'
    )
    return steps
```